# Does $\lim \frac {a_n} {b_n}$ exist and $\lim a_n \neq 0$ imply $\lim b_n$ exist?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac {a_n} {b_n}$ exist and $(a_n)$ converges to some number $k \neq 0$. Is it then possible to conclude that $(b_n)$ converges ?

Also, suppose $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac {a_n} {b_n}$ exist and $(b_n)$ converges to some number $k \neq 0$. Is it then possible to conclude that $(a_n)$ converges ?

I am well aware of the statement that if $(a_n)$, $(b_n)$ converges and $b_n\neq 0$ for $n \ge N$ then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac {a_n} {b_n} = \frac {\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n} {\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} b_n}$. I've tried to use the contrapositive of this statement to prove my hypotheses. It should be said, that this is not an exercise, but something I've been wondering about.

Comment: $$\frac{a_n}{a_n/b_n} = \,?$$

Comment: Thanks ! I cannot believe I haven't thought of that.

Comment: For the second statement, I must also assume $a_n \neq 0$ for $n \ge N$ ??

Comment: Isn't there an extra case when $\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{a_n}{b_n}}=0$? If $a_n\to 0$, we could still have divergence for $b_n$, unless you count $\infty$ as a proper limit. Very pretty way to go about the problem, though.

Comment: No, $a_n$ can be $0$ without problem, there we look at $b_n\cdot \frac{a_n}{b_n}$.

Answer (score 0):

For the first statement you might try to do:$\lim\frac{a_n}{\frac{a_n}{b_n}}$ but if you consider the case where: $a_n=1+\frac 1n$ and $b_n=n$ then $\lim\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\lim \left( \frac 1n+\frac 1{n^2}\right)=0$ and $\lim a_n=1$ but $\lim b_n=\infty$

And for the second part:$\frac{a_n}{b_n}b_n=a_n$

$\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ is converges and $b_n$ is converges and product of two converges series is converges therefore $a_n$ is converges